# Change tag property in Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

How i can change vertical-align: bottom; to vertical-align: baseline; ?

[image]

i tried following:

- Use str.replace in javascript, but it does not work, because I can
  not edit the innerHTML of an element that has not even been created.
- Use css, but the same history, the sdk replace my css.

The tag not is on frame, this must have solution

Comment: Since it has *inline CSS*, unfortunately you have to use notorious `!important` but in a smart way as `.fb_like > span[style] { vertical-align: baseline !important; }` to override the SDK CSS

Comment: wow, now I know the importance of !important (ironic), thanks!